# Return a true statement back to false in Processing

Tags: java, boolean, processing, kinect

I am trying to make an audio sample play when Kinect detects an object in a rectangular region. The problem is that I've currently set it up so that it plays the sample once, then changes the region to not play another sample if I move outside the region.

How do I make it so that it plays it every time I move in the region and reset it after I move out to toggle again?

I've tried using separate Boolean functions like:

```
else if (region1 = true){ 
region1 = false;
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work. I think that I need to work within that function, rather than making a new one to reset it to false.

Heres what I've got so far:

```
boolean region1 = false;

       if (blob.getRect().intersects(screenRects.get(0)) && !region1){
         println("region1-"+millis());
           String filename = dataPath("sample.wav");
               SamplePlayer sp = new SamplePlayer(ac, SampleManager.sample(filename));
               ac.out.addInput(sp);
         region1 = true;
       }
```

Comment: `region1 = true` is an assignment. It has to be `if (region1 == true)` rather than `if (region1 = true)`

Comment: Change `else if(region1 == true)`. `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: adding == true in a condition is moot. simply use if (region1) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you implemented the suggestions in the comments and your code now looks like this:

```
   if (blob.getRect().intersects(screenRects.get(0)) && !region1){
     println("region1-"+millis());
       String filename = dataPath("sample.wav");
           SamplePlayer sp = new SamplePlayer(ac, SampleManager.sample(filename));
           ac.out.addInput(sp);
     region1 = true;
   } 
   else if (region1 == true){ 
     region1 = false;
   }
```

What happens is that when an object in the region is detected, audio plays and `region1` is set true. The very next frame, the `else if` runs and `region1` is set to false again. This means that the frame after that, if the object is still present, the audio plays again.
The `region1`-variable means 'object has entered region', and should only be reset if there is no object present in the region. Try this:

```
boolean isObjectInRegion;

   isObjectInRegion= blob.getRect().intersects(screenRects.get(0));
   if (isObjectInRegion && !region1){
     println("region1-"+millis());
       String filename = dataPath("sample.wav");
           SamplePlayer sp = new SamplePlayer(ac, SampleManager.sample(filename));
           ac.out.addInput(sp);
     region1 = true;
   } 
   else if (!isObjectInRegion && region1 == true){ 
     region1 = false;
   }
```

Meaning: if there was an object in the region, but not anymore, then reset `region1`. It will then trigger the audio when the object re-enters the region.

Comment: It works! Thank you for this, I was having trouble trying to explain what I needed to do. I have 5 other regions adjacent to it and I'll see how far I can push this and if it'll break.

Answer (score 0):

Change `else if(region1 = true)` to `else if(region1 ==  true)` . = is an assignment operator.

Comment: It seems to constantly play the sample unless I move outside the region since its constantly resetting. Is there a way to make it play once when I move in and once again when I move back out and in again?

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that this whole thing happens because of multi-threading? If the changes you make and the querying take place in two different threads, you'll have to take more precautions. eg define the boolean you check as `volatile`.

Comment: That might be the problem. I think I need to find a way to make it not switch to false if it's still inside a region. I just tried ``volatile boolean region1 = false;`` and it doesn't change anything unfortunately.